# Trigger Repaint on Custom DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've changed a property on an object that inherits from DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.  I now need to somehow trigger the Paint() method again to have it redrawn.  How can I do that?

I've tried calling Refresh() on the entire DataGridView:

```
  datagridview1.Refresh()
```

but that doesn't seem to trigger the header cells to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `datagridview1.Invalidate()` method which would force a repaint

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a very old question, thought may help somebody.
Since you have inherited the class from `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, you can use the following code inside the class to force repaint of just single column header.

```
if (DataGridView != null)
    DataGridView.InvalidateCell(DataGridView.Columns(ColumnIndex).HeaderCell);
```